# influxdb 2.0 storage measurements utilization

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

We have an influxdb 2.0 instance that is quickly growing in size (suspect docker metrics), so I would like to find out which measurements are "spamming".

**TLDR:** how do we find the measurements that take up most of the disk space on influxdb 2.0

**Long version:**

- i know old influx had a stats `_internal` db with some relevant metrics, found `_monitoring` in 2.0, but mine is kinda empty, only have `write_errors` measurement there
- tried a bunch of flux queries like, but i don't think they give what i'm looking for:

```
from(bucket: "telegraf")
|> range(start: -15m)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "docker_container_blkio")
|> count()
```

- tried influxQL queries like via the v1 API, like:

```
SELECT COUNT(system) FROM telegraf
```

but that gave:

```
  "results": [
    {
      "statement_id": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

- played a bit with `influxd inspect export-index`, that would also be usefull if it gave me some stats about the measurements
- i saw influxdb 1.8 had this: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/influx_inspect/#report-disk